# Is there an idiom or expression in English for the following situation?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, phrasal-verbs

You scold or tell off someone (or say anything to someone, doesn't have to be negative necessarily) but your true intention is for someone else to hear/see it, and you're just using the first person to get your meaning across indirectly.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The person who is told off is "the whipping boy".

A:"Did you tell the boss off?"

B:"No, but John was with the boss when the boss made the mistake, so I told John off when he was with the boss."

A:"Ah! So you used John as the boss's whipping boy."

B:"Exactly - I think the boss got the message."

OED:

> **whipping-boy,** n.
>
> **A boy educated together with a young prince or royal personage, and flogged in his stead when he committed a fault that was considered to deserve flogging.** Hence the term is used allusively.
>
> 1647   J. Trapp Comm. Epist. & Rev. (1 Tim. v. 20)   *Rebuke before all: yet not as if they were whipping boyes.*
>
> 1841   A. Helps On Choice of Agents in Ess.   *The choice of agents is a difficult matter,..for you have to choose persons for whose faults you are to be punished; to whom you are to be the whipping-boy.*

Comment: "doesn't have to be negative necessarily"

Answer (score 1):

> **hidden agenda** : an ulterior motive [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hidden%20agenda)

I think the headword and its definition here could both work in your example, in fact:

> **ulterior motive**: a secret reason [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ulterior%20motive)